# How to use a variable outside of a for loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert multiple strings into integers and then print use each one of them outside of the for loop.

This is my for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    int p1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Define `p1` as an array outside of the loop.

Comment: The code above does propably not what you want, since p1 is overriden in each iteration. That would be the same as writing int p1=Integer.parseInt(parts[parts.length-1]);

Comment: you want to use the variable outside of the for loop? then declare it **outside** of the for loop!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to access all of the integers you are parsing after the loop:

```
int[] pValues = new int[parts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    pValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
}

// at this point you still have access to the pValues array
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use anything outside a `for` loop (or any other scope, for that matter) you must declare that variable in the scope where you wish to use it:

```
int p1 = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    p1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
}
```

Note that in situations like the above, where a loop sets a single value, a very common thing is to break the loop right after setting the value. Obviously, the value should be set conditionally, otherwise the purpose of the loop would be defeated:

```
int p1 = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (someCondition()) {
        p1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any variables created inside of a loop are LOCAL TO THE LOOP. This means that once you exit the loop, the variable can no longer be accessed! This includes any variables created in the loop signature.

Read more: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html#ixzz3TZ6obLXK

```
 int secondp1 = 0;   // Define your variable outside your loop

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            secondp1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
        }

    //so you can use it here.
    System.out.println(secondp1 );
```

You can see [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html) to check out variable scope and lifetime.

Comment: But then it says it's a duplicate local variable

Comment: I guess you have already have a `p1` variable outside your loop , just rename the variable from inside loop to `secondp1` for instance.  see edited answer above @user3424576